# Integrate ionic3 app with firebase analytics ionic native plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-analytics

I have put the GoogleService-Info.plist at the root of app folder(not the plaforms/ios/), and i build the app in xcode it show error in the below file:

FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:

```
[FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = [FIROptions defaultOptions].bundleID;
```

and the error is:

```
property 'bundle id' not found on object of type 'FIRoptions'
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem?Thanks

Comment: Does your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file contain the correct bundle-id of your app? You can configure the bundle-id in the firebase-console when selecting the settings of an app.

Comment: yes, i have configure a correct bundle-id on firebase console

Comment: Did you try anything to fix it? Remove/readd ios platform?

Comment: @David I have try rm/add the ios platform, but still have this problem.
this plist file place in cordova root app folder or need to put it in platforms/ios/ ? Now so confused, don't know why it have this error.

Comment: You have to place it in the root folder of your project, it will be copied to `platforms/ios/<your-project-name>/Resources` by the plugin.

Comment: ok, then i am doing right, but the plugin have not copied the plist to platforms/ios/<your-project-name>/Resources. I manually put it in Resources, also not working, same error..

Comment: when I add ios platform, I discover have the error:
        Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1
        at ChildProcess.whenDone
And after I imstall the cocopods, the previous error have disappear, but the new error have occur, FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:
@import FirebaseAnalytics;
<-module 'firebase analytics' not found

Comment: The plugin you are using seems to cause a lot of problems (probably because of the required pods), try using this one: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase, analytics works like charm for me with this one.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend using this [**firebase native plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/firebase/). It is working fine.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase
```

But if you need to know more about [**Firebase Analytics then see this great article**](https://pointdeveloper.com/firebase-analytics-for-ionic-apps-logging-custom-events/).

Comment: This article link which you shared is using @ionic-native/firebase-analytics not @ionic-native/firebase. You answer contradicts with the link you shared.

Comment: Yes, it has all. Please read the doc: `This plugin brings push notifications, analytics, event tracking, crash reporting and more from Google Firebase to your Cordova project! Android and iOS supported (including iOS 10).` @ShaharyarKirmani

Comment: Which plugin firebase or firebase-analytics ? these are 2 different plugins.

Comment: I have mentioned the plugin which I have used.i.e. `Firebase` @ShaharyarKirmani